# Are there functions in GML?

Tags: game-maker

I am trying to learn how to use GML to solve [one of my previous prolems](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/178401/way-to-prevent-jumping-pieces), as well as everything I have heard has said it is better to just learn it over DnD. As I have only ever programmed in python I am really fond of my functions, and it is at this point just how I think of code.

Is there any kind of functions similar to pythons in GameMaker?

Comment: I've down-voted this question because it does not demonstrate research effort. Please remember to read the documentation for the tools you're using and do your own search with your favourite search engine to see if you can find your own answers. Don't underestimate your ability to solve problems yourself! :)

Comment: A basic web search for ['functions in gml'](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=functions+in+gml) answers your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes.**

Open your favourite search engine and type in "GameMaker function" or "GML function" - your very first result will be [this page from the official documentation](https://docs.yoyogames.com/source/dadiospice/002_reference/001_gml%20language%20overview/401_16_functions.html):

> The general definition of a function is something like this: A function has an input and an output, and the output is related somehow to the input. In GameMaker: Studio you use functions as part of the program to make things happen in your game and there are a great number of GML (GameMaker Language) functions available to you, all of which are explained in the Reference section of the manual.
>
> **In GML a function has the form of a function name, followed by the input arguments between brackets and separated by commas** (if the function has no input arguments then just brackets are used). Here is an outline of the structure of a function:
>
> `<function>(<arg0>, <arg1> ,... <arg15>);`
>
> Generally there are two types of functions - First of all, there is the huge collection of built-in functions which are used to control all aspects of your game, and, secondly, any scripts you define in your game can also be used as a function (but not always).

You'll also find [this other page from the documentation](https://docs.yoyogames.com/source/dadiospice/001_advanced%20use/006_scripts.html):

> **Scripts**
>
> Scripts are the way in which GameMaker: Studio permits you to **design your own functions**.
>
> ...
>
> **The Script Editor**
>
> When you open the script editor, you should first give your new script a name. This should be something sensible and easy to remember and recognise, and must not start with a number or have any symbols (except the under-bar "_" symbol). **The name you give the script is the one you will use later as a function in code.** It is also a good idea to write some comments at the start of the script (see the above image) to outline the script arguments and how it should be used, especially if you are going to work as part of a team, or plan on using many scripts in your game.

Please remember to put in your best research effort before posting on this site. This is a question that's answerable in five seconds with a search engine or a quick look at the documentation for the tool you're using.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for something similar to `def myFunction ():` in Python, you can use scripts.

In game maker studio, there are many built in functions you can use to design your games. If you want to create your own  custom functions, you can use the a script tool in game maker studio. Once written, script can be called as a function in any game object of your game project.